# Oracle Apex: Region content to fit width not height

Tags: css, oracle-apex

Demo instance: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1:5503592728301

Workspace: DEMO_BARRY

demo/help123456
[image]

I'm working with a new plugin. It looks great, the problem is that it is going to be very big (long).

The demo size is in the second region "small". It looks great.

I made the size 3000 in the first region large to see how it scales to a lot of processes (I'll have hundreds).

But the browser has made it tiny to make it fit in.
[image]

I would like it to be 100pct width with the user scrolling down, so that the font and boxes are the same size as in the "small" region.

I have tried trying many combinations of settings in the regions HTML header, but my CSS/HTML knowledge isn't good enough, so looking for some help.
[image]

Comment: Not a css expert either but found [this](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) article explaining nicely how to size svg objects. I set ```viewBox="0 0 150 150"``` in the svg tag itself (not the page regions !) for the large region and it rendered a lot cleaner.

Comment: Where did you put the change, Koen?

Comment: OK, so on the inspector if I add this manually, it looks a good size. I just need to work out how to get Apex to do this at runtime...

<svg viewBox="0 0 150 1500" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; min-width: 140px; min-height: 385px;"><g><g></g><g><g style="visibility: visible;" transform="translate(0.5,0.5)"><rect x="0" y="0" width="139.81" height="349.53" fill="#e8f5e9" stroke="#e8f5e9" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style="">...